# Use a fixed size for an image in design mode for android

Tags: android, image, resolution

I want to show a fixed 640x640px image on the screen and below that image 2 images that are fixed sized for 128x128px.

In graphical layout, the default(?) width is 320px and height is around 460px so I can't do what I want. I know I should support different screen sizes but for now I want to work with my minimum requirements and then change things according to the screen sizes. How can I "force" the graphical layout to be 640x640 or other standard size which is around that size?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

640*640 is no standard size (no device, as far as I know has a square aspect ratio).
You can emulate a device with a bigger screen size, such as 1280dp by 800dp (WXGA).
By the way, you can't "force" a layout to be bigger than the screen size.

Comment: I didn't mean the image to cover all the screen but to be placed in the center (horizontally) and align top (vertically) so below it, I will place 2 images (128x128). For example, my Samsung S3 won't have a problem with it, my problem is that the graphical layout's sizes are 460x320 so I can't design it like I want it.

Comment: So, you have to scale the image down to 320 by 320 - btw: it's really 480 by 320, a standard resolution (in full screen), not 460 by 320. You can let android do this for you: put the 640 by 640 and the 128 by 128 images in the drawable-xhdpi folder and see the images scaled at other resolutions.

Comment: I sure am missing something, I put the images in xhdpi but I don't see the effect. The AVD is 1280x720 and the images are scaled to fit this resolution though I want them to remain at 640x640 (main image) and 128x128 (2 small images).
--
In graphical layout I can position the images as I want but the sizes are smaller that what I want because the size there is very limited, 480x320 as you said.

Comment: No... you have to give the sizes: layout_width="wrap_content" and layout_height="wrap_content". so, at xhdpi resolution they will fit the image sizes, at mdpi resolution they will be scaled to 320 by 320 and 64 by 64, respectively (I'm not doing the calculations for hdpi and ldpi resolutions).

Comment: That's the thing, I don't want it to wrap_content, I want them to be 640x640 or 128x128 respectively, no matter what is the resolution. I can do that for the 128x128 images but not for the 640x640 image.

Comment: <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/someid"
        android:layout_width="128dp"
        android:layout_height="128dp"

Comment: You see... if you do so, you'll have weird results on lower resolution screens. Consider that in Android all is relative (or it should really be), to make your UI adapt and fit nicely on as most screens as possible.

Comment: So there is no way to put a fixed image size if it's larger than the smallest available resolution? I can always say that the minimal requirements are 1280x720 screens but now I can't implement for that resolution

Comment: You could have your image cropped instead of scaled, by using **src** instead of **background** (only works for ImageViews and MAYBE for ImageButtons). Then play with the various **scaleType** values.

Comment: so if I understand you correctly, the image size will be scaled according to the screen size and I will need to scale/crop it to 640x640 accordingly. Last question in this matter: Maybe I missed it but for the 128x128 image (when there is no size problem) how can I make it fixed on that size so it won't be scaled on higher resolutions?

Comment: If you use android:src="@drawable/your_128_pic", this won't be stretched, instead it will if you use android:background="..."